# Windows server 2012: MSSQL missing .NET 3.5 Framework. Unable to install

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, .net-3.5

The MSSQL installer does not go through - it's missing .NET 3.5 framework to complete.

Unfortunately I've been unable to solve this, what I've tried:

Manually download and transfer the /sxs folder(which should contain the driver) to the C: drive, hereafter running this command in powershell(with admin rights): `install-windowsfeature -name NET-Framework-Core -source c:\sxs` - It does indeed move on to install it, but gets stuck at 68%.

I've also tried downloading and transferring the .NET 3.5 installer itself from Microsoft, and going through the official way of installing it (Server Manager). Same thing applies - it gets stuck roughly 68% into the process, and hereafter just informs that the service-feature could not be installed.

Quite out of options. Help appreciated.

Comment: There should be a much more descriptive error message than "it gets stuck". What does it say in powershell once the installation has failed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install .net 3.5 on Windows server 2012](http://serverfault.com/questions/463604/unable-to-install-net-3-5-on-windows-server-2012)

Comment: @Reaches indeed I get the same trying to update from server manager.

Comment: @reaches you're right. Now that I look at it, it appears that the powershell output is due to lack of internet connection.. But I still have the same problem as the duplicate, the path is provided but it still fails(exactly same)

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14192521/4337899) can help you out then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by copying the .\sxs folder off the installation media for windows 8. Hereafter, I ran the command `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all /source:C:\sxs /LimitAccess` and it installed fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this batch file:

```
@echo off
Title .NET Framework 3.5 Offline Installer
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:.\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
echo.
echo .NET Framework 3.5 should be installed
echo.
pause
```